# Backbone qunit testing: trigger onSelect event on date picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, qunit

I'm trying to write my first qunit tests using my jquery date picker module, right now I want to trigger the onSelect method I am using but this doesn't seem to get picked up in the tests, here is my simple test:

**JS**

```
this.dateSelectorView.$el.on('onSelect', function() {
            assert.ok(true, 'true succeeds');
        });
```

Here is the date picker:

```
this.$el.datepicker({
                dateFormat: Common.DATE_FORMAT,
                showOtherMonths: true,
                selectOtherMonths: true,
                beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                    return _.availableDates(date, Common.availableDates);
                },
                onSelect: function() {
                    Backbone.Events.trigger('date:selected', this.value);
                }
            });
```

Comment: is the date picker a module you have written?

Comment: hey, updated question with my date picker module code which is inside a DateSelectorView

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the view itself, 
when invoking the date picker, trigger the event to the view

```
 onSelect: _.bind(function() {
                    this.trigger('date:selected', this.value);
                },this)
```

I use "bind" to expose the outer scope(the view)

Then, in your View creating the the datepicker, listen to the change event.

```
this.listenTo(this.dateSelectorView, 'date:selected', this.callback);
```

Comment: How does this fit into my test though?

Comment: when the child view triggers 'date:selected' it passes this.value, meaning the parent view listening to this.callback should have a function that receives that argument.

    callback: function (recievedValue) {
        console.log(recievedValue);
    }